# How to specify correct dtype for column of lists when creating a dask dataframe from_pandas?

Tags: python, dask

When creating a dask `Dataframe` with the `from_pandas` method, the formerly correct dtype `object` becomes a `string[pyarrow]`.

```
import dask.dataframe as dd
import pandas as pd

df = pd.DataFrame(
    {
        "lists": [["a", "b"], ["c", "b", "a"], ["b"]],
        "a": [1, 1, 0],
        "b": [1, 0, 1],
        "c": [0, 1, 0],
    }
)

print(df)

       lists  a  b  c
0     [a, b]  1  1  0
1  [c, b, a]  1  0  1
2        [b]  0  1  0

print(df.dtypes)

lists    object
a         int64
b         int64
c         int64
dtype: object
```

I can correctly access the first element of the lists, pandas works as expected:

```
print(df["lists"].str[0])

0    a
1    c
2    b
Name: lists, dtype: object
```

But with dask, the dtype is incorrect:

```
df = dd.from_pandas(df, npartitions=2)

print(df.dtypes)

lists    string[pyarrow]
a                  int64
b                  int64
c                  int64
```

Setting the dtype explicitly also doesn't work

```
df["lists"] = df["lists"].astype(object)

print(df.dtypes)

lists    string[pyarrow]
a                  int64
b                  int64
c                  int64
```

How do I tell dask that this column does not consist of strings?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This seems to be a [known issue](https://github.com/dask/dask/issues/10139#issuecomment-1655928619).

> For people that do store complex data in a column, it would be advisable to set `dataframe.convert-string` setting to `false`, and for columns that contain strings, explicitly provide `string[pyarrow]` dtype when reading data.

So in the above example:

```
import dask.dataframe as dd
import pandas as pd
from dask import config

df = pd.DataFrame(
    {
        "lists": [["a", "b"], ["c", "b", "a"], ["b"]],
        "a": [1, 1, 0],
        "b": [1, 0, 1],
        "c": [0, 1, 0],
    }
)

config.set({"dataframe.convert-string": False})
df = dd.from_pandas(df, npartitions=2)
print(df.dtypes)

lists    object
a         int64
b         int64
c         int64
dtype: object
```

Or setting the value in some other way in the [configuration](https://docs.dask.org/en/latest/configuration.html).